# How to change CreationDate Resource Value

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation, nsfilemanager

I'm writing a recording app that enables the user to trim parts of previous recordings and concatenate them into one new recording.

My problem is: let's say I recorded an hour long track and I want to trim the first 2 minutes of that track. when I'll export these 2 minutes the creation date of this track will be "now", and I need it to match the date these 2 minutes actually took place.

So basically I'm trying to modify the tracks Url Resource Values, but I want to change only the creation date.

Is there a way to do this? or is there a way to add a new resource value key? or a way to attach the needed date to the url?

```
func trimStatringPoint(_ from: Date, startOffSet: TimeInterval, duration: TimeInterval, fileName: String, file: URL, completion: fileExportaionBlock?) {

    if let asset = AVURLAsset(url: file) as AVAsset? {
        var trimmedFileUrl = documentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
        exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A
        exporter?.outputURL = trimmedFileUrl
        let start = CMTimeMake(Int64(startOffSet), 1)
        let end = CMTimeMake(Int64(startOffSet + duration), 1)
        exporter?.timeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(start, end)

        exporter?.exportAsynchronously { handler in

            if exporter?.status != AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
                print("Error while exporting \(exporter?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown")")
                completion?(nil)
                return
            }
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------
        // this code needs to be replaced
        do {
                var resourceValus = URLResourceValues()
                resourceValus.creationDate = from
                try trimmedFileUrl.setResourceValues(resourceValus)
        } catch {
            deleteFile(atPath: trimmedFileUrl)
            print("Error while setting date - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion?(nil)
            return
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------
        completion?(trimmedFileUrl)
    }
```

Comment: Please include some relevant code to your problem.

Comment: I added code to the question, have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried mofifying metadata of the exported recording?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadatacommonkeycreationdate

```
AVMutableMetadataItem *item = [AVMutableMetadataItem metadataItem];
metaItem.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyCreationDate;
metaItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon;
metaItem.value = [NSDate date];
NSArray *metadata = @{ metaItem };
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    exportSession.metadata = metadata;
```